# Calling values in a list of doubles lapply

Tags: r, lapply, quantmod

I'm trying to write a signal function for MACD on a cryptocurrencies list of ticker.

```
MACDs<- lapply(ClosePrices, MACD)
```

returns a list of doubles data which I want to extract as a signal (+1,-1) dependinf if MACD line > signal or else. I have issues when I try to do this

```
MACD.signal<- matrix(0, ncol = 1, nrow = length(ClosePrices[,1]))
                 for (i in c(1:length(ClosePrices[,1]))) {
                   for (t in c(1:length(ClosePrices[1,]))){
                     if(as.double(MACDs[[t]][i][,1])- as.double(MACDs[[t]][i][,2]) > 0){
                       as.double(MACDs[[t]][i][is.na(as.double(MACDs[[t]][i]))]) <- 0
                       #if (is.null(test[[t]][i]) || test[[t]][i] == '') {
                       MACD.signal<- 1
                     }else{
                       MACD.signal<- -1
                     }
                   }
                   
                 }
```

and receive `Error in if (as.double(MACDs[[t]][i][, 1]) - as.double(MACDs[[t]][i][,  :  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

How could I properly do to fix it? Thank you!
PS: Given that I'm downloading data with quantmod package, and can already chart all TA indicators, do I already have a easier way to extract the data series for indicators?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Add some details, like what is included in `ClosePrices`. Basically create a [reprodicuble example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Also note that macd signal column will have 33 NA's if you use the default settings. So you need to take those into account.

Comment: Hi @phiver I don't know why I can't update the question. Anyway the new version of the code works properly, my problem now is that this only works with default settings while I should be able to change it. Any guess? Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.